# MongoDB MapReduce problem, in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, mongodb, mapreduce

I am using mongodb in codeigniter.

collections

```
'mtb'
'road'
'minivelo'
```

php

```
$map = new MongoCode('
    function(){
        ....
    }
');
$reduce = new MongoCode('
    function(key, values){
                 ....
    }
');
$result = $this->mongo_db->command(array(
    'mapreduce'=>$in, // <= 'mtb' 'road' 'minivelo'
    'map'=>$map,
    'reduce'=>$reduce,
    'query'=>array(...)),
    'out'=>'statistics'
));
```

How could I get MapReduce result from several collections?

Answer (score 1):

you can only get results from several collections with several queries. mongodb = no joins.

see this answer:
[MongoDB map/reduce over multiple collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837394/mongodb-map-reduce-over-multiple-collections/3837773#3837773)