# How to source data from multiple collection in DocumentDB to Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, azure-cosmosdb

I'm having a hadoop job which sources data from multiple DocumentDB collection. While configuring the connection with DocumentDB I can set `INOUT_COLLECTION_NAMES` using the following comand

```
 conf.set(ConfigurationUtil.INPUT_COLLECTION_NAMES, inputCollName);
```

My question is what if I have more than just one collection?What if I don't know how many collections I have in advance?

Comment: my main question is when I don't know how many collections  I have in advance. How to get the list of all the collections and add them to the ``INPUT_COLLECTION_NAMES``?

Answer (score 0):

Please look into [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837394/mongodb-map-reduce-over-multiple-collections). Hope it suits your requirement. I think hadoop is best suited for batch process, which means things are not dynamic. happy coding